# Python Requests returns content of other random URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib3

So, I have a strange behavior when trying to scrape a webpage with python requests library. For some reason that I don't understand when I scrape the content of a webpage I get the data of another apparently random webpage. Here's an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_webpage(url):
    """
    Function to scrape some data from given url
    """
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    data = {'event_title': soup.find('h1').text.lower()}
    data['event_date'] = soup.find('li', {'class': 'header'}).text.split()[1]

    return data

# Test URL 
url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/events/67412-ufc-on-espn-33'

# First try returns the correct info
first = scrape_webpage(url)
print(first)   
# {'event_date': '05.16.2020', 'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris'}

# A second try changing nothing returns wrong info
second = scrape_webpage(url)
print(second)
# {'event_date': '06.20.2020', 'event_title': 'efm 3'}

# A third try also fails to retrieve the correct data
third = scrape_webpage(url)
print(third)
# {'event_date': '10.05.2010', 'event_title': 'bystriy fight club 1'}
```

And so this behavior repeats without apparent logic. Also worth to mention is that I'm using Google Colab to do this. If I try to scrape a list of urls only the first one gets the correct data (and only if it's the first try) and the rest returns data from a random url. So the questions is ¿how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mimik a real browser, at least that can be done passing a User-Agent:

```
def scrape_webpage(url):
    #s = session()
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
    }
    """
    Function to scrape some data from given url
    """
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    data = {'event_title': soup.find('h1').text.lower()}
    data['event_date'] = soup.find('li', {'class': 'header'}).text.split()[1]

    return data

# Test URL 
url = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/events/67412-ufc-on-espn-33'

for x in range(10):
    # A second try changing nothing returns wrong info
    second = scrape_webpage(url)
    print(second)
```

Output:

```
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
{'event_title': 'ufc fight night: overeem vs. harris', 'event_date': '05.16.2020'}
```

Comment: Well I didn't know this little detail could cause such weird behavior, thanks!.